# How to change css class attribute from ng directive?

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I have a css class like

```
.container{
  width:55%;
}
```

Now I need to write a directive to change width:82% according to some condition. My directive like this.

```
controls.directive('niMainContain', function () {    
            return {    
                require: '^niContainer',    
                restrict: 'E',    
                transclude: true,    
                replace: false,
                    templateUrl: 'Views/Templates/niMainContain.html',
                    compile: function (scope, iElement, iAttrs, iController) {
                        if (scope[0].parentElement.innerHTML.indexOf("ni-right-aside") == -1) {    
                        $(".contaier").css({
                                'width': '82%' 
                        });

                    }    
                }    
            };    
        });
```

Views/Templates/niMainContain.html template contains ".contaier" class.

Comment: what is `ni-right-aside`?

Comment: Should $("contaier") be $("container") or $(".container")?

Comment: Is it really attribute or value?

Comment: ni-right-aside is a directive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
When system link the directive it is unable to fulfill require. So there need to change '^' to '?' and then System works fine....     
controls.directive('niMainContain', function () {    
                return {    
                    require: '?niContainer',    
                    restrict: 'E',    
                    transclude: true,    
                    replace: false,
                        templateUrl: 'Views/Templates/niMainContain.html',
                        link: function (scope, iElement, iAttrs, iController) {
                           if (iAttrs.$$element[0].parentElement.innerHTML.indexOf("ni-right-aside") == -1) {    
                            $(".contaier").css({
                                    'width': '82%' 
                            });

                        }    
                    }    
                };    
            });
```